# How to get all the reviews within the date range in Google My Business Api?

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

For my application i want to get the reviews for the particular location so that im using below api and its working fine.

```
$location = "*location*";
$access_token = "*token*"; 
$url = "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/".$location_name."/reviews?access_token=".$access_token;
```

How can i get reviews within the date range so far i have tried below code..

```
$url = "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/".$location_name."/reviews?access_token=".$access_token."&startTime=".$start_time."&endTime=".$end_time;
```

The above code is not working please give me any suggestion.

I referred this link [Time range filter link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/TimeRange)

Kindly help me to get the solution.

Comment: `A timestamp in RFC3339 UTC "Zulu" format` are you using this?

Comment: @devpro No i dont want time

Comment: @VinoCoder I am trying to get all reviews. What values to write on `location` and `access_token` ? Can you help please

Comment: You need to get location info from `'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='. $place_id. '&key='.GOOGLE_PLACE_EKEY.''`

Comment: @vijayrana In which programming language you're doing it?

Comment: @VinoCoder Thanks for reply. I am using PHP. I guess you are using `place_id` for `$location` variable. And what about `access_token`, where did you get that value from?

Comment: @vijayrana https://console.developers.google.com/  here you can create your project and you can get access token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but Google doesn't documented the "timeRange" as a query parameter option.

The only options are `pageSize`, `pageToken`, and `orderBy`.

Source: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list

Comment: What to write on `location` and `access_token`? How to get these values? @Jonas

Answer (score 1):

You can try a third-party API as well; if you only need it for a single use you can quickly pull what you need via: https://www.reviewsmaker.com/api/date-range/

The method used by the tool above has a GUI for the RM API which grabs all the reviews and re-loops through the array with the desired date range (thus counting the total number of matches); while it alerts and displays the amount for the Place ID queried; with some JS skills you can easily tweak it to your result;

You can accomplish this using the native GMB API also by parsing all the reviews and storing them in a temp array; and looping through that array where review date is >= your start date variable and <= your end date variable;

In short, it's for sure doable :)